# A Sorted Integer List

Tags: java

So the original code is

```
// An (unsorted) integer list class with a method to add an
// integer to the list and a toString method that returns the contents
// of the list with indices.
//
// ****************************************************************
public class IntList {

    private int[] list;
    private int numElements = 0;
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor -- creates an integer list of a given size.
    //-------------------------------------------------------------

    public IntList(int size) {
        list = new int[size];
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Adds an integer to the list. If the list is full,
    // prints a message and does nothing.
    //------------------------------------------------------------

    public void add(int value) {
        if (numElements == list.length) {
            System.out.println("Can't add, list is full");
        } else {
            list[numElements] = value;
            numElements++;
        }
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns a string containing the elements of the list with their
    // indices.
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    public String toString() {
        String returnString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
            returnString += i + ": " + list[i] + "\n";
        }
        return returnString;
    }
}
```

and

```
// ***************************************************************
// ListTest.java
//
// A simple test program that creates an IntList, puts some
// ints in it, and prints the list.
//
// ***************************************************************
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class ListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        IntList myList = new IntList(10);
        int count = 0;
        int num;
        while (count < 10) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number, enter 0 to quit:");
            num = scan.nextInt();
            if (num != 0) {
                myList.add(num);
                count++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(myList);
    }
}
```

I need to change the add method to sort from lowest to highest. This is what I tried doing.

```
// An (unsorted) integer list class with a method to add an
// integer to the list and a toString method that returns the contents
// of the list with indices.
//
// ****************************************************************
public class IntList {

    private int[] list;
    private int numElements = 0;
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor -- creates an integer list of a given size.
    //-------------------------------------------------------------

    public IntList(int size) {
        list = new int[size];
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Adds an integer to the list. If the list is full,
    // prints a message and does nothing.
    //------------------------------------------------------------

    public void add(int value) {
        if (numElements == list.length) {
            System.out.println("Can't add, list is full");
        } else {
            list[numElements] = value;
            numElements++;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if (list[i] > value) {
                    for (int j = list.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
                        list[j] = list[j - 1];
                        list[i] = value;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (in i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

            }
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns a string containing the elements of the list with their
    // indices.
    //-------------------------------------------------------------

    public String toString() {
        String returnString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
            returnString += i + ": " + list[i] + "\n";
        }
        return returnString;
    }
}
```

The outcome is very wrong. Any one able to steer me in the right direction? I can sort of see why what I have doesn't work, but I can't see enough to fix it.

So I realize I was not very descriptive here the first time. With the exception of the add method modifications the code was not my doing. My assignment is to only touch the add method to sort the array to print out smallest to largest. This is a beginners class and we do little to no practice my only tools for this are some basic understandings of loops and arrays.

I tried redoing it again and came up with this:

```
if(list[numElements-1] > value){

for(int i=0; i<numElements; i++){

    if(list[i]>value){

        for(int j = numElements; j>i; j-- ){

            list[j] = list[j-1];
            }
        list[i] = value;
        break;
        }
        }

numElements++;  
}
else 
{
    list[numElements] = value;
    numElements++;
}
```

my input was:8,6,5,4,3,7,1,2,9,10
the output was: 1,10,1,9,10,1,1,2,9,10

this thing is kicking my butt. I understand I want to check the input number to the array and move all numbers higher than it up one space and enter it behind those so it is sorted on entry, but doing so is proving difficult for me. I apologize if my code on here is hard to follow formatting is a little odd on here for me and time only allows for me to do my best. I think break is not breaking the for loop with i like i thought it would. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: What is wrong about the output?  What have you tried?

Comment: What output? I don't see any. Also, the lack of consistent indentation makes it harder to read.

Comment: If you're allowed to use whatever packages you want, you might want to include Java.util.Arrays which has its own sort function: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_sort_int.htm

Comment: @user1274820 Or, `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest bug I see is using `list.length` in your `for` loop,

```
for(int i = 0; i <list.length; i++)
```

you have `numElements`. Also, I think it's `i` that needs to stop one before like,

```
for(int i = 0; i < numElements - 1; i++)
```

and then

```
for (int j = numElements; j > i; j--)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two lines that have to be moved out of the inner loop:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i] > value) {
                for (int j = list.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
                    list[j] = list[j - 1];
                    // list[i] = value;
                    // break;
                }
                list[i] = value;
                break:
            }
        }
```

In particular, the inner break means that the loop that is supposed to move all larger elements away to make room for the new value only runs once.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to include Java.util.Arrays which has its own sort function:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_sort_int.htm

Then you can do:

```
public void add(int value) {
    if (numElements == list.length) {
        System.out.println("Can't add, list is full");
    } 
    else {
        list[numElements] = value;
        numElements++;
        Arrays.sort(list);
        //Or: Java.util.Arrays.sort(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Eliott remarked, you are getting confused between `list.length` (the *capacity* of your list) and `numElements` (the current *size* of your list).  Also, though, you do not need to completely sort the list on each addition if you simply make sure to insert each new element into the correct position in the first place.  You can rely on the rest of the list already to be sorted.  Here's a simple and fast way to do that:

```
public void add(int value) {
    if (numElements == list.length) {
        System.out.println("Can't add, list is full");
    } else {
        int insertionPoint = Arrays.binarySearch(list, 0, numElements);

        if (insertionPoint < 0) {
            insertionPoint = -(insertionPoint + 1);
        }

        System.arrayCopy(list, insertionPoint, list, insertionPoint + 1,
                numElements - insertionPoint);

        list[insertionPoint] = value;
        numElements += 1;
    }
}
```

That will perform better (though you may not care for this assignment), and it is much easier to see what's going on, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints.

First, `numElements` indicates how many elements are currently in the list. It's best if you change it only after you have finished adding your item, like the original method did. Otherwise it may confuse you into thinking you have more elements than you really do at the moment.

There is really no need for a nested loop to do proper adding. The logic you should be following is this:

1. I know everything already in the list is sorted.
2. If my number is bigger then the biggest number (which is the one indexed by `numElements-1`, because the list is sorted) then I can just add my number to the next available cell in the array (indexed by `numElements`) and then update `numElements` and I'm done.
3. If not, I need to start from the last element in the array (careful, don't look at the `length` of the array. The last element is indexed by `numElements-1`!), going down, and move each number one cell to the right. When I hit a cell that's lower than my number, I stop.
4. Moving all the high numbers one cell to the right caused one cell to become "empty". This is where I'm going to put my number. Update `numElements`, and done.

Suppose you want to add the number `7` to this array:

```
┌─┬──┬──┬─┬─┐
│3│14│92│-│-│
└─┴──┴──┴─┴─┘
      ⬆︎ Last element
```

You move everything starting from the last element (92) to the right. You stop at the `3` because it's not bigger than `7`.

```
┌─┬─┬──┬──┬─┐
│3│-│14│92│-│
└─┴─┴──┴──┴─┘
```

(The second element will probably still contain 14, but you're going to change that in the next step so it doesn't matter. I just put a `-` there to indicate it's now free for you to enter your number)

```
┌─┬─┬──┬──┬─┐
│3│7│14│92│-│
└─┴─┴──┴──┴─┘
        ⬆︎ Updated last element
```

This requires just one loop, without nesting. Be careful and remember that the array starts from 0, so you have to make sure not to get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if your number happens to be lower than the lowest one.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I spotted is that: you are trying to insert the newly added number into the array. However your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i] > value) {
        for (int j = list.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
             list[j] = list[j - 1];
             list[i] = value;
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

is always looped through the total length of the array, which is always 10 in your test, rather than the actual length of the array, i.e. how many numbers are actually in the array.

For example, when you add the first element, it still loops through all 10 elements of the array, although the last 9 slots does not have value and are automatically assigned zero.

This caused your if statement always returns true:

```
if (list[i] > value)
```

if you have to write the sort algorithm yourself, use one of the commonly used sorting algorithm, which can be found in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

If any one was curious I finally worked it out. Thank you to everyone who replied. This is what i ended up with.

```
 public void add(int value)
 {
  if(numElements == 0){
     list[numElements] = value;
     numElements++;

  }
  else{
     list[numElements] = value;
     for(int check = 0; check < numElements; check++){
        if(list[check] > value){
           for(int swap = numElements; swap> check; swap--){
              list[swap] = list[swap-1];
           }
           list[check] = value;

           break;
        }
                 }
                 numElements++;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

so my original is the same but we have to make another class

A Sorted Integer List

File IntList.java contains code for an integer list class. Save it to your project and study it; notice that the only things you can do are create a list of a fixed size and add an element to a list. If the list is already full, a message will be printed. File ListTest.java contains code for a class that creates an IntList, puts some values in it, and prints it. Save this to your folder and compile and run it to see how it works.

Now write a class SortedIntList that extends IntList. SortedIntList should be just like IntList except that its elements should always be in sorted order from smallest to largest. This means that when an element is inserted into a SortedIntList it should be put into its sorted place, not just at the end of the array. To do this you’ll need to do two things when you add a new element:

Walk down the array until you find the place where the new element should go. Since the list is already sorted you can just keep looking at elements until you find one that is at least as big as the one to be inserted.
Move down every element that will go after the new element, that is, everything from the one you stop on to the end. This creates a slot in which you can put the new element. Be careful about the order in which you move them or you’ll overwrite your data!
Now you can insert the new element in the location you originally stopped on.

All of this will go into your add method, which will override the add method for the IntList class. (Be sure to also check to see if you need to expand the array, just as in the IntList add() method.) What other methods, if any, do you need to override?

To test your class, modify ListTest.java so that after it creates and prints the IntList, it creates and prints a SortedIntList containing the same elements (inserted in the same order). When the list is printed, they should come out in sorted order.